# Объединение элементов списка Python

Tags: python

Прошу подсказать как сделать объединение элементов списка с помощью Python.

```
x = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Нужно получить все варианты объединения элементов включая изменение их положения относительно друг-друга в итоговом списке.

```
y = ['12, '123' ... '4325', ... '24513']
```

Начальный элемент `x[i]` не должен повторяться более одного вхождения в `y[i]`

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import permutations

x = '12345'

y = []
for n in range(2, 5+1):
    y += [''.join(item) for item in permutations(x, n)]

print(y)
```

Comment: Гуглить все умеют, но это не это